# Connect R to SQL server in a Remote AWS EC2 Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I’m trying to make queries in R using a SQL Server database hosted in a EC2 Virtual Machine.
This is a Windows Machine and SQL Server has a Windows identification.

I tried with `dbConnect`, `odbcDriverConnect` and `DBI::dbConnect` commands, but I am not be able to make the connection.

Could do you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/165952/connecting-to-mssql-on-ec2-from-local may help?!

Comment: Thank you Shirin! The problem was I was using Windows Autentication instead of SQL one. I change that in the SQL Management Studio in the EC2 server and It worked.